# How to call my method at a particular throughput in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance-testing

I am doing some performance testing so want to call my method at a particular throughput which I can control. With this way I can generate some load and figure out how it behaves under various throughput.

For example: I need to call my `doIOStuff` method at an approximate rate of `x requests per second` from multiple threads where x will be less than 2000 mostly but it really doesn't matter in this case. It doesn't have to be accurate so there is some room for an error but the overall idea is I need to make sure that my method `doIOStuff` is executed no more than x times in a sliding window of y seconds.

Below is the code I got where I am creating 3 different threads and that is calling `doIOStuff` method in parallel but not able to figure out how to rate limit this method for x requests per second. Is there an easy way where I can control this?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        for(int i = 0; i< 100; i ++)
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doIOStuff(), i));

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine("All threads complete");
    }

    // how to call this method at a particular rate?
    static void doIOStuff()
    {
        // do some IO work
    }
}
```

I want to keep running this test for some duration of time but during that duration it should always make calls to that method at a particular throughput only.

**Note:**

This is just an idea from me of generating random throughput which I can control but if this doesn't do things correctly then we should try to do it in a better and efficient way if possible but overall idea is to control the random throughput on my own and generate that much load to my method.

Comment: Shouldn't you keep also an eye to the completion of the tasks that are started? Otherwise, imagine that you start 2,000 tasks per second, but only 1,000 are completed per second. In that case the number of pending tasks would increase by 1,000 every second. After 10 minutes the number of pending tasks would be more than 500,000. Wouldn't it be a problem? My suggestion is to set a limit to the amount of concurrent I/O operations, on top of limiting the amount of operations that are allowed to start every second.

Comment: yeah I want to do the right way basically. Since I am pretty new to what I am doing so I came up with that logic but if there is some better way by which this can be done correctly then we should do it that way only. @TheodorZoulias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method you could use to stress test an asynchronous `doIOStuffAsync` method:

```
public static async Task<long> StressTestAsync(
    Func<CancellationToken, Task> taskFactory,
    TimeSpan duration,
    int concurrencyLimit,
    int tasksStartedPerSecondLimit,
    IProgress<long> progress = default,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    long successfullyCompletedCount = 0;
    using (var linkedCTS = CancellationTokenSource
        .CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken))
    using (var progressTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ =>
    {
        progress.Report(Interlocked.Read(ref successfullyCompletedCount));
    }))
    {
        var concurrencySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(concurrencyLimit);
        var perSecondSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(tasksStartedPerSecondLimit);
        var completionSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
        int pendingCount = 1; // The initial 1 represents the while loop
        var exceptions = new ConcurrentQueue<Exception>();
        linkedCTS.CancelAfter(duration);
        if (progress != null)
            progressTimer.Change(1000, 1000); // Report progress every second
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                await concurrencySemaphore.WaitAsync(linkedCTS.Token)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
                await perSecondSemaphore.WaitAsync(linkedCTS.Token)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { break; }
            ReleaseSemaphoreAfterOneSecond();
            StartOneTask();
        }
        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref pendingCount) == 0)
            completionSemaphore.Release();
        await completionSemaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); // No token
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        if (!exceptions.IsEmpty) throw new AggregateException(exceptions);

        async void ReleaseSemaphoreAfterOneSecond()
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000, linkedCTS.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { } // Ignore
            finally
            {
                perSecondSemaphore.Release();
            }
        }

        async void StartOneTask()
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref pendingCount);
            try
            {
                var task = taskFactory(linkedCTS.Token);
                await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
                Interlocked.Increment(ref successfullyCompletedCount);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { } // Ignore
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exceptions.Enqueue(ex);
                linkedCTS.Cancel();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref pendingCount) == 0)
                    completionSemaphore.Release();
                concurrencySemaphore.Release();
            }
        }

    }
    return Interlocked.Read(ref successfullyCompletedCount);
}
```

Usage example:

```
await StressTestAsync(
    taskFactory: async ct => await doIOStuffAsync(ct),
    duration: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
    concurrencyLimit: 1000,
    tasksStartedPerSecondLimit: 1000);
```

The `concurrencyLimit` parameter is the maximum number of tasks that can be running concurrently at any given moment. The `tasksStartedPerSecondLimit` parameter is the maximum number of tasks that can be started during any 1-second time span. These two limits compete with each other, so normally only one of them will be the limiting factor of the throughput. If the tasks are fast, the `concurrencyLimit` will be the limiting factor. If the tasks are slow, the `tasksStartedPerSecondLimit` will be the limiting factor.

The `StressTestAsync` does not tolerate exceptions. Any exception thrown by the `taskFactory` method, or if any of the created tasks completes in a faulted state, will cause the termination of the test.

A [`Progress<long>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) can be passed as an optional argument, to propagate progress reports about the current number of successfully completed tasks.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. So this `3000` tasks at `3` seconds time span means 1000 requests per second as of now to `doIOStuffAsync` method? Correct me if I am wrong here. if yes, then only these parameters I need to change to get my actual throughput I need?

Comment: @dragons yes 3000/3sec is equivalent to 1000/1sec, provided that each task won't take more than 1 sec to complete on average. Otherwise the limiting factor will be the concurrency limit, and you'll have less throughput with the 1000/1sec configuration.

Comment: @dragons I changed the API by replacing the somewhat confusing parameter `taskMinimumDuration` with the `tasksStartedPerSecondLimit`, which should be more intuitive.

Comment: yeah that looks better now. So in regards to your previous comment - if a task doesn't take more than 1sec then it's always gonna be 1000 request per second for that configuration right? But if some tasks do take longer time so in that  case throughput might be less (which is fine but was just making sure). Also `duration` field is telling program to run for that long right - in this case it will run for 30 seconds and throughput will be 1000 requests per second.

Comment: @dragons dragons yeap, this is exactly the expected behavior of the method.

Comment: @dragons it is a [cancellation token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken). If the method you are testing is not cancelable, then change the line: `Func<CancellationToken, Task> taskFactory` to `Func<Task> taskFactory`, and the line `taskFactory(linkedCTS.Token)` to `taskFactory()`. This will have the effect that the test is not going to stop at exactly the `duration` requested. It will go on until the currently running tasks are completed.

Comment: @dragons ...or leave the method as is, and just don't use the supplied token: `taskFactory: async ct => await doIOStuffAsync(),`

Comment: yeah I got that after looking around. I will fix that.

Comment: It works fine. I tested it with simple method which only prints `Hello World` and with config as `concurrencyLimit:200`, `tasksStartedPerSecondLimit: 200` and `duration: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)` I can see total qps is `6000`  after tests finishes so cool. Thanks for your help! Now I am gonna figure out how much time my executed method takes on an average, 95th percentile after the tests finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you start n threads and want a maximum of m calls per second. This can be achieved by having each thread generate a random number between 0 and 1, k times per second and call your IO method only if the generated number is less than m / n / k

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;


namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        const int m_threads = 100;
        const int n_throughput = 2000;
        const int k_toss_per_second = 2000; // Note that k_toss_per_second x  m_threads >= n_throughput

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();



            for (int i = 0; i < m_threads; i++)
                tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => callDoIOStuff()));

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("All threads complete");
        }


        static void callDoIOStuff()
        {
           int sleep_time = (int) (1000 * 1.0d / k_toss_per_second);
           double threshold = (double) n_throughput / m_threads / k_toss_per_second; 
           Random random = new Random();
           while (true) {
                Thread.Sleep(sleep_time);
                if (random.NextDouble() < threshold)
                    doIOStuff();
            }
        }

        // how to call this method at a particular rate?
        static void doIOStuff()
        {
            // do some IO work
        }
    }
}
```

You need to take care of passing the cancellation tokens and whatever parameters. This code sample is quick and dirty using global variables and could be greatly improved.

Comment: can you provide an example on how will this work basis on my code if possible? This will help me to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to execute it given amount of time per period of time.

Create 2000 instances of `Action` type which will represent `DoIOStuff` methods. Then try to start 2000 tasks with this action but only you can get it within 1 second (`TakeWhile`).

```
var period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
var maxAmountOfCalls = 2000;

var methods = Enumerable.Range(0, maxAmountOfCalls)
    .Select(_ => doIOStuff)
    .ToArray();

var watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();

var tasks = methods
    .Select(method => Task.Run(method))
    .TakeWhile(task => watch.Elapsed < period)
    .ToArray();

watch.Stop();

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This approach will start less than required amount if time period is short.

Comment: so this means it is making 2000 qps to `doIOStuff` method? And if I need to change that then I can switch `2000`  to any number which will give me that much qps. Correct?

Comment: How different is this from a simple loop with a sleep of 1/2000 of a second between each call?

Comment: @Tarik, only that with this method I don't need explicitly create empty collection of tasks and then add task to that collection i the loop.

Comment: The code doesn't match the description. What really happens is that 2000 tasks are instantly enqueued and how long they take to execute is left undefined. (It's also a very roundabout way of doing this - that method array is completely unnecessary because it's the same every time)

Comment: @Voo, there are no requirements to record an execution time for the methods - goal is to  execute given method given amount of times within given period of time.

Comment: @Fabio If you do this repeatedly and you cannot execute 2000 tasks in one second you'll get more and more of a backlog.

Comment: @Voo, all tasks will be completed before next execution, that what `Task.WhenAll` does.

Comment: @Fabio Yeah but assuming that a single task takes say half a second to execute, that `Task.WhenAll` will block much longer than the 1 second and you'll also swamp the thread pool with 2000 tasks thereby causing congestion.

Comment: Congestion will be caused anyway, because OP needs to execute synchronous IO operation asynchronously. Instead I would suggest to make `doIOStuff` properly asynchronous (`doIOStuffAsync` :)) - then similar code(without `Task.Run`) would do same thing but on the one thread